# Error in genereting_fuction(100) : could not find function "genereting_fuction

Tags: r, function, sample

I created this function to generate the data with the characteristics I need:

```
genereting_fuction<-function(n){
  
  X1=rnorm(n)+mean_shifts[1]
  X4=rnorm(n)+mean_shifts[4]
  X2=X1*p12+std_e2*rnorm(n)+mean_shifts[2]
  X3=X1*p13+X4*p43+std_e3*rnorm(n)+mean_shifts[3]
  X5=X2*p25+X3*p35+std_e5*rnorm(n)+mean_shifts[5]
  sample=cbind(X1,X2,X3,X4,X5)
  return(sample)
}
```

if I call it for a single item it works but when I call it in the applay function as follows:

```
dati<-lapply(1:100, genereting_fuction(100))
```

I get this error:
Error in genereting_fuction(100) :
could not find function "genereting_fuction"

Comment: Didn’t you accidentally delete the function from your namespace?

Comment: It may also be a spelling mistake.

Comment: Also, the syntax is `dati<-lapply(1:100, genereting_fuction, n=100)`, assuming the idosyncratic spelling is correct, which will generate a list of 100 matrices, each with 100 rows.

Comment: I also inserted `genereting_fuction<-is.function(match.fun("genereting_fuction")) `  . I ran your line of code but it shows an error of missing function argument

Comment: Could you try this `dati <- replicate(100, genereting_fuction(100))`

Comment: Or possibly `dati <- lapply(rep(100, 100), genereting_fuction)`

Comment: `dati <- lapply(1:100, function(x) genereting_fuction(x))`

Comment: I used the syntax in your second to last comment and it worked.
Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that I prefer the replicate solution by @Jakub.Novotny for your purpose, but to understand what went wrong using lapply, this is why and how to solve it.

Using apply and a function, it assumes `x` the value of your apply to be provided always in the function.

To make it work you can do two things.

1. `lapply(1:100, function(x) genereting_fuction(100))`
2. include x in your function like `genereting_fuction <- function(x, n) { # code here }` and then you can use `lapply(1:100, genereting_fuction, n = 100)`